# Preventing a Dash dropdown menu from reseting to default value in multi-page app

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I am currently trying out building a multi-page app in Python's Dash (changing a bit some of the materials from the tutorials) and I am wondering how you are able to prevent a dropdown menu in e.g. the first page from going back to the default value when you are returning to that page.

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content'),
])

index_page = html.Div([
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 1', href='/page-1'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 2', href='/page-2'),
])

page_1_layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='page-1-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['LA', 'NYC', 'MTL']],
        value='LA'
    ),
    html.Div(id='page-1-content'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 2', href='/page-2'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go back to home', href='/'),

])


page_2_layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='page-2-content'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 1', href='/page-1'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go back to home', href='/')
])

@app.callback(Output('page-1-content', 'children'),
              [Input('page-1-dropdown', 'value')])
def page_1_dropdown(value):
    return html.Div([
        html.Div(['You have selected "{}"'.format(value)]),#
    ])

# Update the index
@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/page-1':
        return page_1_layout
    elif pathname == '/page-2':
        return page_2_layout
    else:
        return index_page
    # You could also return a 404 "URL not found" page here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

In the example above, when I select e.g. 'NYC' from the dropdown menu, and then move to page 2 before moving back in pg 1, the dropdown selection has gone back to the default 'LA'.

It seems to be pretty straight-forward to prevent that, but I have not found a way to do it yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [State](https://dash.plot.ly/state) for this. So record the event state for the drop down, so if it was clicked mark the state. And in your callback for `page_1_dropdown` check for the state and update to selected value. Something on the lines of :

```
@app.callback(Output('page-1-dropdown', 'value'),
          [Input('page1_link', 'n_clicks')],
          [State('page-1-dropdown', 'value')])
def drop_down(n_clicks, input1):
    if (n_clicks) >=1 :
        return(input1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work by turning on persistence = True:

```
dcc.Dropdown(
        id='page-1-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['LA', 'NYC', 'MTL']],
        value='LA,
        persistence = True   
    )
```

You can read more about this here: https://dash.plotly.com/persistence